# Getting underlying layer data in entry form

Tags: qgis

We have a requirement to place a point feature on a line feature (a road) in QGIS.

When placing the point, we would like the road number from the line feature to be automatically populated in the data entry form of the point feature attributes.

We are using out of the box features of QGIS to connect to WFS/WMS and MSSQL spatial. We have tried the spatial analysis features of qgis, but they always expect the results the be saved as an external .shp file, and not back to the database. We have also tried varous field calculators to make a spatial query on the fly from the roads layer but not successful. We would like to know if making spatial query on adding new point is the generally accepted practice, or like DPSSpatial suggested that we do it after the fact using triggers.

Comment: is PostGIS an option for data storage? That way you can use a trigger to update the value of the ROAD_NUMBER field from the underlying data that intersects using a spatial function...

Comment: @DPSSpatial WFS, MSSQL Spatial, and ArcGIS Server are all options. If this can also be done easier with ArcDesktop we can also look into that.

Comment: If you're using QGIS I would suggest checking out PostGIS for this

Answer (score 3):

You can combine default values and a custom Python function.

In the default value of the road number field of the point layer, edit the default value:

1. In the function editor, add a new method by using this code:

```py
from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_line(feature, parent):
    line_layer_id = '_YOUR_LAYER_ID_'
    line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(line_layer_id)
    candidates = line_layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(feature.geometry().boundingBox()))
    for line_feat in candidates:
        if line_feat.geometry().intersects(feature.geometry()):
            return line_feat.id()
    return None
```

click "save and load functions" button

2. For the expression, just use `get_line()`

some remarks:

- this works only if the layer have the same CRS, you need to transform them if they are not
- instead of returning the feature id, you can either return the whole feature or just the field you want (`return line_feat['_MY_ROAD_NUMBER_FIELD_']`)
- you can make the layer ID (and the field name) arguments of the Python method (`def get_line(line_layer_id, feature, parent)`) and call them from the QGIS expression (`get_line('_YOUR_LAYER_ID_')`)